# How to use Python Elasticsearch mget() API

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I want to fetch documents with multiple ids using _mget API of elasticsearch python.

I'm using `es.mget()` method on a Elasticsearch object. However, I don't know what to provide as an argument to body param. should it be comma separated list of ids or a list of docs with `_id` mentioned.

I've tried both ways and I keep receiving an exception:

`elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError`

Answer (score 20):

`mget()` is used when you retrieve multiple document via document id.
You should pass `body = {'ids': [doc_id1, doc_id2]}` as describe [ES Multi GET API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-multi-get.html)

```
 es_client.mget(index = 'bank',
                doc_type = 'account',
                body = {'ids': ['100', '101']})
```

Comment: is it possible to put the index as a value*? I dont know forsure which index the id is in since I am using index-datestamp

Comment: @ScipioAfricanus No, you can't. You must know the specific index that the id belongs. If you search against multiple indices, I suggest to use search API. It has multi-index feature. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html#search-multi-index

Comment: search is less effecient than mget, no? I know exactly the ids I am after. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @ScipioAfricanus Yes, retrieving via doc_id is the fastest way. Although search API supports search by `_id` field (like `POST /idx-*/_search { "query": { "bool": { "should": [ { "term": { "_id": "id1" } }, { "term": { "_id": "i2" } } ] } } }`), it scans all shards of index so it is slow. I think https://discuss.elastic.co/ is better place to ask you questions than my answer.